# Is $\frac{\ln2^{n+1}}{1}$ equal to $\frac{\ln2^{n}*\ln2^{1}}{1}$ or $\frac{\ln2^{n}2^{1}}{1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Well i am not sure about this.
I have something like this $$\frac{\ln2^{n+1}}{1}$$
And i dont know what is corret can i extend it like this?
$$\frac{\ln2^{n}*\ln2^{1}}{1}$$
Or this one is correct?
$$\frac{\ln2^{n}2^{1}}{1}$$

Comment: This is not at all clear.  Why do you write all those $1's$ as denominators?  Of course $\ln (2^{n+1})=\ln (2^n\times 2^1)$ since $2^{n+1}=2^n\times 2^1$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: both are wrong $\ln(a\cdot b)=\ln a + \ln b$, $\ln 2^{n+1}=\ln 2^n+\ln 2=(n+1)\ln 2$

Comment: @Vasya  I simply assumed $\ln 2^n2^1$ to mean $\ln (2^n2^1)$.  But it isn't clear what the OP meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $a,b>0$, we have that
$$
\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b).
$$
In particular
$$
\ln(2^{n+1})=\ln(2^n\times 2)=\ln(2^n)+\ln 2
$$

Comment: Ou thank you very much :)